# .htaccess file rewriterule, Don't get parameter from seo friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have below .htaccess file

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^category/([^\.]+)$ category.php?catname=$1 [NC,L]
```

it redirects to category.php file but i don't get `catname` param.

```
if (!isset($_GET["catname"])) {

    echo "<br/>category not found";
    
    exit;
}
```

it prints category not found when i try to redirect...

`https://mydomain.co.in/category/home-and-garden`

i want `home-and-garden` to be printed...

Comment: code seems legit. `var_export($_GET);` gives `array ( 'catname' => 'home-and-garden', )`
as others say `.htaccess` may not took effect

Comment: @anubhava yes when i put random text on top of .htaccess file it gives me error,
500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @anubhava what is next if its enabled?

Comment: @anubhava i have tried it but its not working...

Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^category/([^\.]+)$ /category.php?catname=$1 [NC,L,R]

Comment: @anubhava still not working i have only 4 lines in .htacess file
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([^\.]+)$ /category.php?catname=$1 [NC,L,R]

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /category.php?catname=$1 [NC,L,R] `

Comment: @anubhava still its not working

Comment: It simply means either .htaccess or `mod_rewrite` is not enabled.

Comment: @anubhava but when i put random text on top of .htaccess file it gives me error, 500 Internal Server Error –

Comment: @anubhava if 404 page displays which i set custom page for that and i got that page when 404 error occurs it means mod_rewrite is not enabled ?

Comment: No custom 404 page is not outcome of `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good, have u enable apache mod_rewrite module ?

Comment: How can i enable it in server or live hosting panel ?

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then restart apache